# Contacts not being collected from "Soccer Club Homepage" tutorial

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to google apps scripts and I am following the tutorial at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sites_tutorial and when I run the myContact function from step 1, no contact info is populated into my spreadsheet.

I have a group created called AZ_Pilot, and I have the myContact function set up as follows:

```
function myContact() {
  var contacts = ContactsApp.findContactGroup("AZ_Pilot").getContacts();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setValue(contacts[0].getPrimaryEmail());
}
```

The script runs with no errors, but nothing is updated within the spreadsheet. It's a bit embarrassing to be stumped at step 1, but here we are.

Comment: Add `Logger.log(contacts[0].getPrimaryEmail());`, and run again. Then view-logs, and see if you have an email address.

Comment: Here's the output:    [13-06-11 15:40:16:709 EDT] null

Comment: Well, that's your explanation. No contacts.

Comment: The contacts are there, and it finds them (I can see them in the debugger), but it doesn't seem to be finding their email addresses, though those are there too.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `getActiveRange()` which is the range which is currently under selection in the spreadsheet. By default, it is the first cell in the spreadsheet. Maybe you have a different cell selected and therefore, the email might be written to a different cell. Try keeping the first cell in focus and running the function again.

Also, you haven't mentioned whether or not there are any contacts in the group you created :)

Comment: I verified that the first cell in the spreadsheet is highlighted. I also have contacts in the group. When I open the spreadsheet, I click the tools menu and choose script manager. Then I click the Run button next to my function. I assume that's the correct way to do it?

Comment: Thats the right way. Can you also change your Logger.log statement suggested by Mogsdad to print out the name of the contact group 
Logger.log( ContactsApp.findContactGroup("AZ_Pilot").getName()); 

Finally, findContactGroup is deprecated. Replace it with getContactGroup

Comment: The logs show "AZ_Pilot", so the group is good. When I set a break point in the script and run the debugger, I can see that it finds 9 contacts, which is correct. However, when I step into the line with the getPrimaryEmail, the debugger tells me there was an error and to try again in a bit. The only way this does not happen is if I change getPrimaryEmail to getId. From what I can see in the contacts themselves, there is a valid email address for each one, so I'm not sure what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

I was adding some additional logging information, and it just started working correctly with no change to the functional code. Not sure what happened there.